# Jacoco code coverage details missing on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jacoco

I am trying to use the code coverage tools of Jacoco on a Jenkins server for my Android library.
The builds are successful, and the code coverage stats are shown in the report :

[image]

However, when I want the details of which lines are covered or not, the page is totally empty:

[image]

As this is the thing I need the most, this is pretty annoying...

Here is the part of the gradle file I have for Jacoco:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    // Use this version for upper ones are broken (with Gradle)
    // https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/288
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

// Edit covered scope if needed
def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../s3papiandroidclient/src'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: '../s3papiandroidclient/build/intermediates/classes',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testUnitTestDebug.exec')

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

}

jacocoTestReport.doFirst{
    delete fileTree (dir: "../s3papiandroidclient/build/intermediates/classes", include: "**/*Test.class")
}
```

Anyone encountered something similar ?

Regards,
Gyoo.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. In my case the plugin is looking for the source code in the wrong place. You should take a look at the Jenkins log to see where it's looking.